# Does WeChat in app browser supports self signed https url?

Tags: html, web-applications, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, wechat

I have a web application in my local WAMP server, which is self signed SSL enabled. that made my app url as

```
https://myipaddress:port/demoapp/index.html
```

When I ping the above url in WeChat chat window and click on the link, it is not opening my demoapp home page but just blank page. When I paste same link as with http as `http://myipaddress:port/demoapp/index.html`. WeChat browser is opening my demoapp homepage without any issues?
Any clues how to open `https` urls from WeChat in app Browser?

Answer (score 1):

Yes WeChat in app browser is not allowing Self Signed certificates unlike Chrome, where it will ask whether to Trust or Block. I tried placing my demoapp in a server, which has valid `DigiCert SHA2 CA` certificate and it is working in WeChat.